# Iter() during loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I'm having trouble understanding why `issup("oFB","FooBar")` is returning False. How does `iter(t)` behave during this loop?

refer to this 
https://leetcode.com/problems/camelcase-matching/
https://leetcode.com/problems/camelcase-matching/discuss/270029/JavaC%2B%2BPython-Check-Subsequence-and-Regax

I'm guessing `iter(t)` starts at `"FooBar"`, then goes to `"ooBar"` the next iteration and so forth.

```
def issup(s, t):
    it = iter(t)
    return all(c in it for c in s)
```

Comment: No, `iter` returns an iterator over the container, or if you call `iter` on an iterator, it should just return the iterator itself. It will be single pass.

Comment: You shouldn't need `iter` here.  Just use `return all(c in t for c in s)` or `return set(s) <= set(t)`

Comment: Also, *please do not provide links as substitutions to problem descriptions*, please **describe the problem you are trying to address in the question yourself**

Comment: @0x5453 indeed, depending on what you are trying to do, `iter` here will make this incorrect. because the iterator is single pass, it will only ever return `True` for `x in it` **exactly once**, so if `s` has a length greater than `1`, the function **will always return false**

Comment: An ``iter`` is single-use only! Once it has been traversed, there are no ore elements in it. ``o in it`` advances the iterator to the fourth position, after which there is no ``F``. Your function will only return True if the characters in ``s`` occur in the correct ordering in ``t``.

Answer (score 2):

`iter(t)` returns an iterator that returns all the elements of `t`. So it will return `"F"`, `"o"`, `"o"`, `"B"`, `"a"`, and `"r"`.

However, an iterator can only be used once; once it has returned all the elements, it will be empty. So the first time that the generator executes `c in it`, it will step through the iterator until it finds a match for the value of `c`. When it tries to look for the next `c`, it will continue from where it left off the previous time. And if any of them doesn't find a match, it will reach the end of the iterator and none of the following `c in it` tests will succeed.

So when you do `issup("oFB", "FooBar")`, the first iteration finds the first `o`. The second iteration looks for `F`, but it can't be found because we're already past that element in the iterator. At this point, `all()` returns `False`.

Many Python errors are due to not realizing that iterators can only be stepped through once. E.g. something like this:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for _ in range(10):
        for line in f:
            # do stuff
```

`f` is an iterator over the lines of the file. When you reach the end of the `for line` loop, there's nothing left in it, so the next iteration of `for _` will not have anything to loop over. In this case you can actually fix it with `f.seek(0)` to rewind, but most iterators don't have something like this. The `file` iterator is unusual in that it uses the state of the underlying stream, rather than keeping state of its own.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now.

Comment: This is a good answer. One warning about the last part though: Files are rather unusual iterators as they *can* be rewound after they've reached the end, using `seek` (or maybe just by waiting for some other program to extend the file on disk). This is technically against the iterator protocol, which says that an iterator that has been exhausted should stay exhausted. But rules are meant to be broken I guess. This answer is correct that most iterators don't work that way.